# error while passing data to directive in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have this simple directive:

```
angular.module('app')
  .directive('ppBubble', function () {

    function PpBubble($scope, $element, $attrs) {
      var vm = this;
      vm.message = $attrs.message;
      vm.isSent = $attrs.sent;
    }

    return {
      templateUrl: '../views/directives/ppBubble.html',
      restrict: 'E',
      controller: PpBubble,
      controllerAs: 'vm',
      bindToController: true
    };
  });
```

And here is how I use it:

```
<pp-bubble ng-repeat="msg in vm.messages" sent="{{msg.sent}}" message="{{msg.message}}"></pp-bubble>
```

The problem is that I see this "msg.message" instead of the string this object attribute hold:
[image]

Here is the messages array:

vm.messages = [
      {
        sent: true,
        message: "aasdasd dsfsdfd"
      }, ...
]

I am probably missing something stupid :(

Comment: What's your console errors ?

Comment: No errors seen in the console

Comment: That's ok, I figured it out beforehand, see the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what worked for me:

```
function PpBubble($scope, $element, $attrs) {
    var vm = this;
  }

  return {
    templateUrl: '../views/directives/ppBubble.html',
    restrict: 'E',
    controller: PpBubble,
    controllerAs: 'vm',
    bindToController: true
  };
});
```

Also i removed the {{}} from the html:

Thanks to @Omri Aharon

Comment: Glad you figured it out :)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you're doing `vm.message = $attrs.message;` and you're taking the string literally, which means: `{{msg.message}}`, since that's the text that's written in that attribute:

`message="{{msg.message}}"`.

You need to work with a scope to make Angular work its binding magic, and take the data from there:

```
 function PpBubble($scope, $element, $attrs) {
    var vm = this;
    vm.message = $scope.message;
    vm.isSent = $scope.sent;
  }

  return {
    templateUrl: '../views/directives/ppBubble.html',
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: { message: "=", sent: "=" },
    controller: PpBubble,
    controllerAs: 'vm',
    bindToController: true
  };
```

Here is the messages array:

```
vm.messages = [
      {
        sent: true,
        message: "aasdasd dsfsdfd"
      }, ...
]
```

**EDIT**: Another thing is that now that you're binding from the directive, you need to bind to the variable itself, and not to its string literal, meaning to remove the `{{}}` from the directive HTML:

```
<pp-bubble ng-repeat="msg in messages" sent="msg.sent" message="msg.message"></pp-bubble>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/10990/)

Comment: Now, I am getting this error: `Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token '{' invalid key at column 2 of the expression [{{msg.message}}] starting at [{msg.message}}].`

Comment: @vlio20 Missed a coma at the end of the scope declaration, that might be it.

Comment: Nope, I have added it :(

Comment: @vlio20 Then it's some silly bracket missing.. hard to tell from here. Can you click on the error ? It points you to the faulty line,.

Comment: Looks like you have `{msg.message}}` instead of a `{{msg.message}}`. Could be ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70926/discussion-between-vlio20-and-omri-aharon).